# how i can secure html password tag from spaces by php?

Tags: php

hello i explore that when somebody try to write spaces in password field php handle with it as chatter .so how i can prevent it . pleas i want if try to write space get message say dont try to write space

Comment: Why do you want to prevent space characters in passwords?

Comment: i would suggest you do a client-side validation on your pass first.Let javascript see if your password is ok and if it is, then send it to the server.it would save you ( the user) a lot of time.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to prevent people from entering some characters in the password. I sometimes use spaces in passwords, and if you hash your passwords, then length and character sets allowed shouldn't give you any problems.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (strpos($_POST['password'], ' ') !== false) {
    echo "Don't try to write space.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
if (strpos($_POST['password'], ' ') !== false) {
    echo "Don't try to write space.";
}
```

BUT... the arguement that Thai(look above) gave is a good one.
You shouldn't restrict the user from being able to use spaces and other characters in their password.

```
    $upass = $_POST['password'];
    $usalt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,7);
    $upasshash = sha1(md5($upass).$usalt);
```

Now store the userinformation in your database.
For security reasons please clean the $_POST['username'].
Also use trim to clean the fields for unnecessary spaces.

```
    $upass = trim($_POST['password']);
    $uname = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
    //Get the from data.
    $usalt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,7);
    $upasshash = sha1(md5($upass).$usalt);  
    //Salt for extra security (prevent attackers from using rainbow tables)

    $sql =  "   INSERT INTO users (uname, upasshash, usalt)
            VALUES ('$uname', '$upasshash', '$usalt');";
    mysql_query($sql);
```

An advantage is that you do nmot create overhead in your database on the password field.
The `$upasshash` is allways 40 characters long.

**UPDATE:**
This is a way to login the user.

```
$mysqlcon = dbconnect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$unamein';";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){ //Does the user exists and is it only 1 user?
//Yes 1 match exacly
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(sha1(md5($upassin).$fetch['usalt']) == $fetch['upasshash']){ //Are the password hashes equal?
    //Yes the hashes are equal
        $_SESSION['check'] = true;
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $fetch['uid'];
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $fetch['uname'];
        $message = 'Login succeded!';                           
    }else{
    //NO the hashes ar not equal
        $message = 'Wrong password and/or username.';
    }
mysql_close($mysqlcon);
}else{
// USER doest exist.
    $message = 'Wrong password and/or username.';
}
```

**For security reasons, please do not tell them which field they filled in incorrectly.**

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a check in JavaScript to improve user experience (faster response time than doing a server round trip). In case you go for this route, don't rely on it exclusively since a user could have JavaScript disabled and also add a check in PHP.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Form Validation</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function validate() {
     var pass = document.myForm.passwd.value;
     for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
         if (pass.charAt(i) == ' ') {
             alert("Please don't use spaces in the password");
             document.myForm.login.disabled = true;
             return;
         }
     }
     document.myForm.login.disabled = false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method='post' name='myForm'>

<input type='password' name='passwd' id='passwd' onblur='validate()'/>
<input type='submit' name='login' id='login'/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```